# In Nodejs/Express js i am unable to return response to Angular 6

Tags: express, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and Nodejs/Expressjs to avoid cross domain issue. So here is my code

In Angular i am calling:

```
this.httpClient.post('/uploadFile',  formData, {params: params})
.pipe(map((res: any) => {return res}),
catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {})
```

Nodejs/Expressjs:

```
app.post('/uploadFile', (req, res) => {   
let formData
const form = new IncomingForm();
let readStream;

form.on('file', (field, file) => {
console.log('file.path>>>',file.path);
readStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);   
});
form.on ('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
//rename the incoming file to the file's name
let fileName = file.path.split("\\");
fileName[fileName.length-1] = file.name.split('.')[0];
fileName = fileName.join("\\");
file.path = fileName;
console.log('file.path', file.path);
console.log('file.name', file.name);
})
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", readStream);
formData.append('package_name', req.query.packagename);
formData.append('type', req.query.type);
formData.append('version', req.query.version);
formData.append('descr', req.query.descr);

console.log('req.query.packagename',req.query.packagename);
const axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
};
let uploadRequest = request.post("WebAPiCallURL", requestCallback);
uploadRequest._form = formData;     
uploadRequest.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
function requestCallback(err, res, body) {
    return JSON.parse(body);            
}
}); 
});
```

From requestCallback i am unable to send response to Angular6

Comment: Duplicate Of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: It is not about cors. i can access other api calls data in  angular. But only for this particular where i am making web API call from nodejs to upload file i am getting response but not able to send back to angular.

Comment: Where is `res.send` in your API call ?

Comment: If i do that i am getting error because it is taking res reference from callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not sending response from to the client. To send you can use `res.send` or any of the [response function](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res)  from Expressjs.

```
    function requestCallback(err, response, body) { //Rename res to response to avoid conflict
        res.send(body); // Send Response to Client
    }
```

***Note :*** As you used same variable `res` for request, Rename to some other name